# can't get rsync with exlude to work!

Tags: rsync

I have the source directory :  /media/Documents/source

and inside 'source'  ,dir1,dir2 etc..

I am trying:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh  --exclude /dir1 --exclude /dir2  /media/Documents/source user@192.168.1.3:/media/Documents/
```

but it keeps transfering dir1 ,dir2 to destination.

I have tried various ways:

```
--exclude=/dir1 

 or --exclude dir1/
```

or `--exclude 'dir1'` etc.. but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--exclude 'dir1/'`should work. One thing to keep in mind is that the pattern that you use (in your case "dir1/" is a relative pattern to your source.

The geek-stuff blog has some good examples on how to use rsync with exclusions:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/

Comment: :But it doesn't work..I already checked that blog..

Comment: It's important to use the trailing `/` in your case `--exclude 'dir1/'`. The files that you have excluded will still remain at your destination unless you remove these manually or specify `--delete-excluded`.

Comment: :OK!Now I need help!!!I used "rsync -avzhe ssh  --progress  --delete-excluded '/home/user/temp/test1/'  /home/user/temp user@192.168.1.3:/home/user
" to test it but it deleted all /home/user in 192.168.1.3 !Any way to reverse it???

Comment: Your command should include `--exclude 'dir1/'` as well if you want to use the `--delete-excluded`. Your command replicates the files from your host to the remote host, but removes the folder that you did include in your exclusion filter. So for your test folder that's
`--exclude 'test1/' --delete-excluded temp user@192.168.1.3:/home/user/temp`

Comment: :Ok ,that did it,thanks (I have to format my drive of course due to the previous deletion)